# How to save a bread without enough water

Tags: bread, wholewheat

I am ready to do the final rise before baking my bread and I realized I didn’t get the hydration up to where I would like it. Can I just knead the extra water in now?

It’s a 1/2 whole wheat bread with seeds and pieces. Hydration is currently 65% which is fine for a white bread but for whole wheat it should be around 75-85.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is certainly possible to rescue a too dry dough this way. The amount of water absorbed can shoot up very quickly. I suggest you copy [Gérard Rubaud's technique](http://www.farine-mc.com/2012/04/troubleshooting-dough-hydration-trick.html) and knead very gently, using stretch-and-fold, so that some of the air from the first rise stays in the bread.  Then give it a final rise as usual.